# Is Glassfish an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)?

Tags: java, glassfish, esb

I was arguing with a coworker about ESBs.  I mentioned that Glassfish is an ESB as it manages database transactions, provides SOAP messages, and messaging systems through JMS.  He disagreed and said that Oracle Enterprise Service Bus is an ESB whereas Glassfish isn't.  I asked him what features make an ESB and he couldn't respond.

**What is Glassfish lacking that prevent it from being an ESB?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish has a bunch of the components of an ESB, but what it is specifically lack in the orchestration component. The orchestration is managing the "wiring" of the various services to each other. GF has all of the capability in terms of managing the endpoints, but not the routing and transformation of messages from endpoint to endpoint.

That said, it USED to have an ESB bundled with it. It used to ship with OpenESB in GF 2.x, but that's been removed from GF 3.x.

Comment: More specifically, GlassFish v2.x shipped with the JBI core runtime and a Java EE Service.  GlassFish v2.x was never an ESB in-and-of itself.  A separate project, GlassFish ESB, was the foundation for Java CAPS. This project included JBI binding components, services, and a message bus.  As Will mentions, GlassFish 3.x does not include any remnants of JBI nor an ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish is an application server.  You could certainly run an ESB on top of it, but there are several features missing out-of-the-box from what is typically considered an ESB.  You're kind of comparing apples to oranges here -- an app-server provides the structure that supports a web application, whereas the primary goal of an ESB is to help distribute information to/from potentially several applications.